# Unknown error when launching Dota 2 __Failed to read: 11110118 bytes -Very complicated issue-

Tags: steam

First of I would like to state that I consider this a complicated issue because there is nothing on google regarding this error code. It's no where to be found so I hopefully someone here has encountered this and fixed it.

I try to launch Dota 2 from Steam and I get this error message :

> Failed to read: 11110118 bytes

Anyone have any idea on what could be the problem cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else has the same problem too. :(

But it appears to be resolvable.

In your `Steam` Client, right-click `Dota 2` and select `Properties`. Then select `Local Files` and then `Verify Files`. Let it finish the process.

It should work after that.

If you have any comments, concerns, or questions. please fill free to comment on this answer!.

P.S. For more information, see [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/570/discussions/0/666827247971888088/) forum post.